# Is there a way to configure my PC's network adapter to reach a device on a separate subnet?

Tags: networking, subnet

I recently changed my router situation -- I added an Orbi mesh network and then my ISP changed so everything is behind a new AT&T router/modem. The Orbi is configured as an access point behind the AT&T equipment. In the process, my LAN subnet changed from 10.0.1.X (or whatever that address bitmask is.../24?) to 192.168.1.X.

Trouble is, I have a Lutron device that had a static IP on the old subnet at 10.0.1.121 that I want to update -- if only I could connect to it.

Is there any way I can coax either my PC running Windows 10 to connect to that device *without* reconfiguring my routers and booting all the devices off (there are so many other ridiculous smart home devices that I want to try and minimally disrupt the delicate balance between convenience and deep regret). Some magic routing table I futz around with on my PC?

All devices are physically connected, if that somehow helps.

Comment: is it an option for you to just connect your computer directly to your Lutron device and just use that static IP address as your gateway? or possibly just reset it so you can configure it with a new address?

Comment: In my experience you can usually get the login for the AT&T device and adjust the LAN settings to your desired settings - you should be able to log in (contact them if they didn't provide the login info) and set the LAN network back to what you used to have.